# Function parallelized with mp.Pool() taking longer execution time with each iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I parallelized a function that (i) generates a list of sublists (ii) parameterizes a matrix with each sublist and (iii) returns the eigenvalues of the matrix. I parallelized step (ii) and (iii) so that the eigenvalue calculation for each sublist is parallelized. Then I run this function for many iterations but when I am monitoring the execution time  for each iteration I observe that every execution of the function takes longer and longer (iter 1 -0.705 mins, iter 2 - 0.711 mins, iter 3 - 0.717 mins and so on). The pseudocode is given below

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def parallelized_func():

      global calc_eig
      pool = mp.Pool()

      def calc_eig(sublist):
         max_eig = other_module.parameterize_and_decompose(sublist)
         return max_eig

      list_of_sublists = some_generator.generate(n_sublists = 100)
      max_eig = pool.map(calc_eig, list_of_sublists)
      pool.close()

      return max(max_eig)


for iter in range(10000):
     start = time.time()
     this_max_eig = parallelized_func()
     end = time.time()
     print(end-start)
```

I am not sure why the executions are taking longer with each iteration. I am monitoring memory and core utilization through `htop` and there doesn't seem to be any abnormalities. I also checked the other modules I am using inside the function and they do not have increasing execution times so I am guessing the problem is the way I am using `Pool`. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: The usage of `Pool` seem correct -- are you sure it's not the eigenvalue calculator that is accumulating state and slowing down? You could try to build a new one every time. It would also be useful to modify the script into something that we can run to reproduce.

Comment: Why are you recreating the pool over and over again for each iteration in `parallelized_func` rather than just creating it once in and passing it as an argument to that function?

Comment: @PietroSaccardi could you please elaborate on what you mean by accumulating state ?

Comment: @bistrodank I mean that `calc_eig` might not be brought back to its original state after solving a given problem. There might be history, cache, or simply allocated memory lying around that make the object be progressively slower. It might not be necessarily a bug even, maybe that's the intended usage but it perform poorly in this specific application.